# how to handle multiple instance of audio files in react-wavesurfer for reactJS?

Tags: reactjs, wavesurfer.js

I am using wavesurfer package to play audio files. I am using state variable to play, pause audio files which are in loop but i am facing issue to play specific file when i press play button it plays all file because i am using state variable to play as 'playing' variable.please see above code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Wavesurfer from 'react-wavesurfer';
window.WaveSurfer = require("wavesurfer.js");
let Regions = require("react-wavesurfer/lib/plugins/regions").default;
let Minimap = require("react-wavesurfer/lib/plugins/minimap").default;

class DashboardPage extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    this.state = {
      recordings:objectOfRecordings,
      playing: false,
      pos: 0
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleTogglePlay = this.handleTogglePlay.bind(this);
    this.handlePosChange = this.handlePosChange.bind(this);
    };
   handleTogglePlay() {
    this.setState({
      playing: !this.state.playing
    });
  }
  handlePosChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      pos: e.originalArgs[0]
    });
  }

    render(){
    const { recordings } = this.state;
    return(
        <div>
            <h1>Dashboard</h1>          
          <div className="recording">
            <ul className="list-group">
            {
              recordings &&
              recordings.map((prop,key)=>{
                return (
                  <li className="list-group-item" key={key}>
                    <Wavesurfer
                      audioFile={prop.comment_url}
                      pos={this.state.pos}
                      onPosChange={this.handlePosChange}
                      playing={this.state.playing}
                    />
                    <button onClick={this.handleTogglePlay}>play</button>
                  </li>
                )

              })
            }
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Dashboard;
```

Please suggest me better solution to play specific file.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the central state for configuring multiple recordings in stored in the parent component with a boolean variable.

There are two options forward from here:

1. Move the playing boolean `playing` state and `position` state to inside a separate `Recording` component, because they are internal to it. But this comes with a disadvantage. You cannot stop the one already playing before starting the next, (this is not stated in the question, I'm just guessing)
2. The second would be to store the ID of the recording being played inside `playing` state variable and using it to trigger `wavesurfer`. This approach allows you to have exactly one playing at a time. To control the position individually, it is moved inside a separate component.

For eg:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Wavesurfer from 'react-wavesurfer';
window.WaveSurfer = require("wavesurfer.js");
let Regions = require("react-wavesurfer/lib/plugins/regions").default;
let Minimap = require("react-wavesurfer/lib/plugins/minimap").default;


class Recording extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.state = {
      pos: 0,
    }
    this.handleTogglePlay = this.handleTogglePlay.bind(this);
    this.handlePosChange = this.handlePosChange.bind(this);
  }
  handleTogglePlay() {
    const { id, onChange } = this.props;
    onChange(id);
  }
  handlePosChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      pos: e.originalArgs[0]
    });
  }
  render() {
    const { data } = this.props;
    return (
      <li className="list-group-item">
         <Wavesurfer
           audioFile={data.comment_url}
           pos={this.state.pos}
           onPosChange={this.handlePosChange}
           playing={this.props.playing}
         />
         <button onClick={this.handleTogglePlay}>play</button>
      </li>
    );
  }  
}
class DashboardPage extends Component{
   constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      playing: -1,
      recordings:objectOfRecordings,
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.changePlaying = this.changePlaying.bind(this);
   };

   changePlaying(id) {
     this.setState({
       playing: id,
     });
   }

   render(){
    const { recordings } = this.state;
    return(
        <div>
          <h1>Dashboard</h1>          
          <div className="recording">
            <ul className="list-group">
            {
              recordings &&
              recordings.map((prop,key)=>{
                return (
                  <Recording 
                    data={prop}
                    key={key}
                    id={key}
                    playing={key === this.state.playing}
                    onChange={this.changePlaying}
                  />
                )

              })
            }
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```